# On back pressed activity is blank

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is my onClicklistner

```
        readMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReadMore.class);
            i.putExtra("song", song);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

and here is other activity where i do finish

```
 back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
```

but when i do like this its work but its take to long to do on pressed back 6 sec

```
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            this.finish();

        }

        private void finish() {
            finish();
        }


    });
```

Comment: when i do finish or on back pressed all screen is white

Comment: You are using base activity ? then may be it is still exist in back stack.

Comment: just set `onBackPressed();` instead of `finish();`

Comment: i did .. see im going to add a way who work but not good its take to long

Comment: Why are you application context for Intent creation?

Answer (score 1):

*I hope this Will Help You.*

```
public void onBackPressed() {
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Really Exit?")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            WelcomeActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }).create().show();
```

}

Comment: is not this what i need but ty

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         super.onBackPressed(); 
      }
 });
```

Comment: not working i did it its work only if i do like this.finish() but its take 6 sec to do that

Answer (score 0):

**Use finish() here**

Instead of this

```
readMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReadMore.class);
            i.putExtra("song", song);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });`
```

use the following

```
readMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ReadMore.class);
            i.putExtra("song", song);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });`
```

Hope this help!!!

Comment: hmmm the problem is i have 3 activitys ...activity 1 on click i go in te 2 ...2 i go to 3 ... 3 on back i go to activity 2 ..if i do in activity 2 the finish is not returning to activity 2 but to the 1

Comment: You just close the old activity whenever go to new one, it will solve your problem..

Comment: and to return i have to do the intent again ?

Comment: Yes you need create new activity again